# Display Multiple notifications with different images on a single Tile in Metro apps?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, push-notification, winjs

I have a metro application in which,on my application Tile I want to display 2 different images with some number.This images and number should be changed whenever my service updated.I did a push notification for displaying single icon.But am not able to get 2-images with notifications?Can anyone give me suggestion to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are only able to use the "templates" provided by the tile manager. The list is available on [MSDN, with examples of what they look like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761491.aspx).

If you *really* need to display them SxS, then you can always use a hidden `<canvas>` to generate your image, and then save it to disk.